# Difference between fastLm and fastLmPure functions from RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

Here is an example:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(RcppArmadillo)
require(zoo)
require(repmis)

myData <- source_DropboxData(file = "example.csv", 
                              key = "cbrmkkbssu5bn96", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

dolm = function(x) coef(fastLmPure(as.matrix(x[,2]), x[,1]))

myCoef = rollapply(myData, 260, dolm, by.column = FALSE)

summary(myCoef) # 80923 NA's

dolm2 = function(x) coef(fastLm(x[,1] ~ x[,2] + 0, data = as.data.frame(x)))

myCoef2 = rollapply(myData, 260, dolm2, by.column = FALSE)

summary(myCoef2) #  0 NA's
```

In the example above first method with `fastLmPure` produces NAs in output, while second method with `fastLm` doesn't.

Here is the link to `fastLm` & `fastLmPure` functions written in R:

https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/R/fastLm.R

And here is the link to underlying `fastLm` function written in C++:

https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp

From these links and RcppArmadillo's documentation it's not obvious to me what causes the difference in outputs? Why there is no NAs in second ouput? And the most important question what routine / part of code prevents NAs from appearance in the second method and how is it implemented?

Comment: I would invite you to [read the source code](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/R/fastLm.R). It is really not that complicated ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks, I've found the issue. PS. But giving the link which is already provided in the question is very helpful ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling *two different functions* with *two different interfaces*.

In particular, `fastLm()` when used via a *formula* `y ~ X` will rely on the R internal (and slow !!) functions to create a vector and matrix for you corresponding to `fastLm(X, y)`.

Here is a trivial example setting things up:

```
R> data(mtcars)
R> lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data=mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
    cyl     disp       hp       wt  
 5.3560  -0.1206  -0.0313   5.6913  

R> fastLm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data=mtcars)

Call:
fastLm.formula(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
      cyl      disp        hp        wt 
 5.356014 -0.120609 -0.031306  5.691273 
R> fastLm(mtcars[, c("cyl","disp","hp","wt")], mtcars[,"mpg"])

Call:
fastLm.default(X = mtcars[, c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt")], y = mtcars[, 
    "mpg"])

Coefficients:
      cyl      disp        hp        wt 
 5.356014 -0.120609 -0.031306  5.691273 
R>
```

Now lets add an `NA` in both the left- and right-hand sides.  For ease of indexing we will use an entire row:

```
R> mtcars[7, ] <- NA
R> lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data=mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
    cyl     disp       hp       wt  
 5.3501  -0.1215  -0.0332   5.8281  

R> fastLm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data=mtcars)

Call:
fastLm.formula(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt - 1, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
      cyl      disp        hp        wt 
 5.350102 -0.121478 -0.033184  5.828065 
R> fastLm(na.omit(mtcars[, c("cyl","disp","hp","wt")]), na.omit(mtcars[,"mpg"]))

Call:
fastLm.default(X = na.omit(mtcars[, c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt")]), 
    y = na.omit(mtcars[, "mpg"]))

Coefficients:
      cyl      disp        hp        wt 
 5.350102 -0.121478 -0.033184  5.828065 
R>
```

And here is the kicker: the results are *still the same between all methods provided we are consistent about the missing values*.